# How to link cell within googlefinance formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

I'm trying to get the `googlefinance` formula to work for multiple country exchanges.

e.g. Tencent is listed on Hong Kong stock exchange, the code is 0700.

If I put `=googlefinance(HKG:0700,"price")`, it works, but I want to link the `0700` part to another cell, so it will look like `=googlefinance(HKG:A2,"price")`.

But I can't type `A2` physically, because it will not be treated as taking the content of cell A2.

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation with `&`:

```
=googlefinance("HKG:"&A2,"price")
```

[image]

Note that I had to put `'0700` in A2, or change the cell format to 'plain text'; just typing in 0700 will result in Google Sheets converting it automatically to 700.